# What's the purpose of 1> in exec 1> >(logger -s -t tagname) 2>&1?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, exec

I just stumbled over

```
exec 1> >(logger -s -t $(basename $0)) 2>&1
```

which is used to redirect the output of the current script to the system logger (in case you've never seen this, but are interested check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888251/understanding-bash-exec-12-command to broaden your shell knowledge).

I am wondering why the `1>` is necessary. It seems necessary because `exec >(logger -s -t test) 2>&1` fails due to

```
bash: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
bash: exec: /dev/fd/63: cannot execute: Permission denied
```

Omitting `1>` is however what I'd do intuitively because `exec >[some redirection target]` already should be sufficient for the redirection according to the question linked above. `2>&1` then redirects the stderr to stdout as usual.

I'm using bash 4.4.19.

Comment: @mosvy I see, thank you. I just learned about process substitution, i.e. didn't know that `>(...)` means that. I'd accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is necessary (the extra `>`, not the `1`, `1>` could be simply written `>`). The `>(...)` *process substitution* will expand to something like `/dev/fd/13` (a file name), and then `>` will redirect the standard output into it. Thence `> >(...)`.